# Regex: select only urls from an unusual string

Tags: regex

In my old database there are fields of such content:

```
a:2:{s:6:"item-0";a:1:{s:17:"siteurl";s:25:"https://www.urlsite.com/";}s:6:"item-1";a:1:{s:17:"siteurl";s:29:"https://urlsite2.org/";};a:1:{s:17:"siteurl";s:29:"https://urlsite3.com/";}}
```

I need to select only the url from this, so that something like this happens:

```
https://www.urlsite.com/,https://urlsite2.org/,https://urlsite3.com/
```

At the moment I use this construction:

```
.*?(http.*?(\.org|\.com))
```

However, I get this result:

```
https://www.urlsite.com,https://urlsite2.org,https://urlsite3.com,/";}}
```

It is not possible to select the end of the line after the last url and it gets into the result.

```
,/";}}
```

Comment: If there is a trailing comma in the output, will it still be fine as expected output? You must be using `\1,` or `$1,` as replacement pattern,  and the comma will have to be inserted upon each replacement. The best way to handle such scenarios is collecting all matches, and then joining the string list with a comma.

Comment: Simply `"(https?:[^"]+)"` would find the URLs, then join the results. Or use [unserialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) on the data, which might be more future-proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JavaScript implementation:

```
const text =
  'a:2:{s:6:"item-0";a:1:{s:17:"siteurl";s:25:"https://www.urlsite.com/";}s:6:"item-1";a:1:{s:17:"siteurl";s:29:"https://urlsite2.org/";};a:1:{s:17:"siteurl";s:29:"https://urlsite3.com/";}}';

const result = text.match(/http.*?(.com|.org)\//gm);

console.log(result.join(','));
```

Results in:

```
https://www.urlsite.com/,https://urlsite2.org/,https://urlsite3.com/
```